# Jenkins Failed to Parse POMs: Permission Denied

Tags: maven, jenkins, permissions, openshift

I have been having issues getting my new OpenShift Jenkins CI Server to work. I setup everything the way all tutorials tell me to, but when I try to build the project, I always get this same error:

```
Checking out Revision 3e88dcb5295354f9b02ef69ded84c97562c39aad (origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 3e88dcb5295354f9b02ef69ded84c97562c39aad
 > git rev-list 3e88dcb5295354f9b02ef69ded84c97562c39aad # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:330)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory$SocketHandler$AcceptorImpl.<init>(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:210)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory$SocketHandler.call(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:196)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory$SocketHandler.call(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:194)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:266)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:778)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am using Maven 3.3.9 and have made sure that all permissions are correct. This is a fresh install of OpenShift Jenkins with the only changes being adding JDK 7u79, GitHub plugin (including updating all dependencies for it) and adding Maven 3.3.9, however it is denied permission to the POM making it unable to be read.

I have seen this question [OpenShif jenkins: java.net.BindException: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884325/openshif-jenkins-java-net-bindexception-permission-denied)
However the link provided in the answer is outdated and no longer present, simply redirecting me to the documentation which does not help.

How can I allow my Jenkins server permission to allow it to parse the POM file and build my code?

Answer (score 0):

Check your jenkins configuration :

1. scm Plugins
2. jenkins->configure system

Comment: Uhh that's the problem. I'm not sure what to check. I've never setup Jenkins (or any other CI) before other than Drone.io which is mostly automatic...

Comment: can you please give more input? you are selecting which option from scm

Comment: Honestly I am not exactly sure what that means either, but I believe it is the method of getting the code correct? If so, it's Git. I have the Git plugin and GitHub plugin installed too with all of their dependencies. Sorry I'm trying to do this for the first time so I have never had to deal with Git terms and things like that often.

Comment: Here is the settings I have for the project:
`
GitHub project: https://github.com/WolfLeader116/WolfUpdater/
Platform: linux
Git: https://github.com/WolfLeader116/WolfUpdater.git
Credentials: Github Username and Password
Branches to build: */master
Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built: true
Trigger builds remotely: true (with the same token in both GitHub and on Jenkins)
Build when a change is pushed to GitHub: true
Root POM: pom.xml
Goals and options: clean install
And finally the post-build action I have is to archive target/*.jar
`

Comment: for using git scm jenkins you should installe 2 plugins . git client and git plugin

Comment: already have all of the dependencies for the git plugin along with the plugin itself installed.